# thinning out the deck chairs, turning over the barstools

Tags: phrase-meaning

Sunbelt states rush to line up hospital beds, not barstools
July 1, 2020

ST. PETERSBURG, Fla. (AP) — Florida and other states across the Sunbelt are **thinning out the deck chairs, turning over the barstools** and rushing to line up more hospital beds as they head into the height of the summer season amid a startling surge in confirmed cases of the coronavirus.

Source: [AP](https://apnews.com/article/health-us-news-ap-top-news-virus-outbreak-public-health-b42fb52eaa5ba19956cca0c7aabd9a52)

In the phrase "thinning out the deck chairs, turning over the barstools", do "the barstools" refer back to "the deck chairs"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.

Obviously, there is a repetition of a type of seat, which is not accidental, but a deck chair is quite different from a barstool.

Deck chairs and barstools are both associated with Florida's tourist industry. But the two words make no direct reference to each other.